# 180-W PSU for i9-9900

Tags: power-supply

In [HP ProDesk 400 G6](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06388142#AbT2)'s specification you can see i9-9900 is supported. And it has a 180-W power supply. If I install an i9-9900 (non-K) on it and bring it to high load, is this power supply enough? I don't use graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a good practice to overspec your power supply more than all the rest of your components (use 45-70% is ideal). Intel CPU's since that generation also use a lot of power, so maybe it is enough, but overspecing is always a good idea (500W is more than enough and can be had cheaply from reputable brands)